# C# XMLReader ReadString how to read everything include nested xml in an element?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmlreader

My xml file with sample data as following

```
 <FRUIT>
 <HTML><B>1.</B> Apple</HTML>
 <HTML><B>2.</B> Banana</HTML>
 </FRUIT>
```

and my code

```
XmlReader xmlr = XmlReader.Create(myxmlfile);
while (xmlr.Read())
{
  if ((xmlr.IsStartElement()) && (xmlr.Name == "HTML"))
  {
    // this will return blank string!
    html = xmlr.ReadString();
  }
}
```

I need to get the full string of `<B>1.</B> Apple`

How could I read everything inside HTML element with ReadString()?

Comment: What is you requirement here? Is the structure of xml fixed? And the name of the element you want to read, will that be known beforehand?

Comment: Yes the xml structure is fixed and the name of the element in this case "HTML" is known beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the structure is fixed and you know the elements before then you can do this:

```
 List<string> bananas = new List<>string();
 string contents = string.Empty;
    xmlr.ReadToFollowing("HTML");
    do
    {   
        contents = xmlr.ReadInnerXML();
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contents))
        {        
            bananas.Add(contents);  
        }

    }while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contents))
```

Also read [XMLReader on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XmlReader(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: I modified my code as

      while (xmlr.Read())
      {
        if ((xmlr.IsStartElement()) && (xmlr.Name == "HTML"))
        {
          xmlr.ReadToFollowing("HTML");
          html = xmlr.ReadInnerXml();
        }
      }

But it will only get the value of <B>2.</B> Banana

Comment: Can you please paste the desired output in your question? Do you want the all the HTML elements as separate strings? You are getting a single HTML element and that is what you asked for right? If there are two elements you are overwriting the value every time in While loop. You should put html += xmlr.ReadInnerXMl() instead of html = xmlr.ReadInnerXml()

Comment: Ok actually i need to store all the html into a list

      var htmllist = new List<string>();  
      while (xmlr.Read())  
      {  
        if ((xmlr.IsStartElement()) && (xmlr.Name == "HTML"))  
        {  
          xmlr.ReadToFollowing("HTML");  
          htmllist.Add(xmlr.ReadInnerXml());  
        }  
      }

So i only get Banana in the list.

Comment: Err sorry... I mean i only get banana in the list which is not correct...
I need to get everything into the list. Your updated code will only get banana.

Comment: So are you not getting Apple in the list? I have updated the code again. If you are using .net 3.5(or above) and performance is not an issue than you can use LINQ which has better construct and easier options.

Comment: Your new code only get Apple in the list. No banana.
The actual xml file is huge and so performance is an issue.

Comment: This is possibly because it is moving forward twice. I have updated the code again. But I would strongly recommend you read MSDN once. I am doing too!